# RabbitMQ .NET client does no raise errors immediately

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Here is a simple program that uses `RabbitMQ.Client` version 4.1.1:

```cs
var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");
var cf = new ConnectionFactory();
using (var conn = cf.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = conn.CreateModel())
{
    int i = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i++);
        channel.BasicPublish("nonexistent", "", body: message);
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to post to an exchange that has not been declared on the server. This causes an error, namely 404, `NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'nonexistent' in vhost '/'`, to be thrown. However, the error is not thrown immediately on the first `BasicPublish` call, but rather randomly down the line. I had it being thrown after 8, 22, 40 calls to `BasicPublish` etc. `ModelShutdown` event is raised only after the exception so it doesn't help either.

The question is, why doesn't it throw immediately so I can detect the error and take action? It behaves as if a number of publishes succeeded when in reality they didn't. What can I do to make the client behave predictably? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that the `BasicPublish` when returns does not guarantee that the message is arrived on the RabbitMQ server. So, you cannot have an immediate exception when you try to publish to a not existent exchange.

I think you can try two different approaches:

- declare the exchange before the publish so you don't have to worry about the presence of the exchange
- use a "reliable" publish approach: publish confirms or transactions (you can find more info [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/))